# vscode - Completely exclude directory from project

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm having trouble excluding typescript files from the .tmp directory of my project in visual studio code. They still show up when searching (Quick Open) via windows+P, but more annoyingly VS code goes to the wrong file when pressing F12 to open the definition of a typescript class / method. (I have copies of the files served up by my server so that my source maps work when debugging in firefox). Optimally I'd like visual studio to not know that the .tmp directory even exists. I can hide it from the explorer view but this is not enough.

Here's a screenshot of my issue:

[image: screenshot of search]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [at this VSCode issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10919)

It looks like the excluded files may be coming from the editor history. [This issue tracks applying `search.exclude` to the editor history as well](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6502)

Comment: Thanks - I tried using the "clear editor history" command and it looks to be a decent temporary workaround until they fix the bug.